# C++20 move only ranges: gcc vs clang on istream_view copy

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I have simple istream_view and then I am trying to use ranges::copy on result.

```
auto t = ranges::istream_view<int>(is);
ranges::copy(t, std::back_inserter(v));
```

[Live example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1ro9x3nh1)

GCC does everything ok, clang fails with error:

```
error: no matching function for call to object of type 'const std::ranges::__copy_fn'
  ranges::copy(t, std::back_inserter(v));
```

Probably it is because istream_view is moveonly view.

How to argue in this case who is right?

Standard C++20 [range.istream.overview] have similar example:

```
auto ints = istringstream{"0 1 2 3 4"};
ranges::copy(ranges::istream_view<int>(ints), ostream_iterator<int>{cout, "-"});
```

Which also fails in clang (and this is definitely a bug but I am not sure that reason is the same for both compile-time errors).

Comment: [Clang trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/z5j7WTMco) compiles it, too.

Comment: Like the answer to the duplicate, this is a Clang bug, but it seems to be fixed in trunk.